# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named cli.plugins.foo - How to build a plugin system?

Tags: python-3.x

I've built a python (3.6) CLI that should allow plugins to be loaded by namespace `cli.plugins`.  The plugins should be separate testable repositories, that import modules like `cli.utils` for common functionality.

If the CLI has a folder structure:

```
 - cli
  - __init__.py
  - utils
   - plugins.py
   - __init__.py
```

And the plugin has the folder structure:

```
 - cli
  - plugins
   - foo
    - bar.py
    - __init__.py
 - tests
  - test_bar.py
```

How can my test `test_bar.py` in the plugin find `bar.py` when Python has loaded `cli` from the CLI package? In other words, if two packages start with the same namespace, are they unable to import the other?

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the following: [Creating a namespace package](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/)...

> It is extremely important that every distribution that uses the namespace package omits the **init**.py or uses a pkgutil-style **init**.py. If any distribution does not, it will cause the namespace logic to fail and the other sub-packages will not be importable.

I removed the `__init__.py` from root of the CLI.  After this, all the modules in the CLI were importable into the plugin, and the CLI was able to run the plugin.

```
- cli
  - utils
   - plugins.py
   - __init__.py
```

```
 - cli
  - plugins
   - foo
    - bar.py
    - __init__.py
  - tests
   - __init__.py
   - test_bar.py
```